# DataSource.groovy error

Tags: grails

I am pretty new to Grails and am trying to learn things from the 'Grails in Action' book. I have this example which asks to change the dataSource url in the DataSource.groovy file and when I do that I get an error. Here are the changes and the error. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance,

previous:

```
dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
```

After Change:

```
dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:devDB;shutdown=true"
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
    Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory':
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties':
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector':
      Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
    Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
    Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:hsqldb:file:devDB;shutdown=true' (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: you changed it based on the book or what? It seems the database you specified doesn't exist. Also, did you add the hsqldb library to `/lib` ?

Comment: Yes I changed it according to what the book says. I did not add any items specifically to the /lib folder. Should I?

Comment: No, the H2 jar comes with Grails, so there's no need to put a jar in the lib dir. And in general avoid this - use dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: I have the Grails plug installed in the Spring Tool Suite and am sorry I dont know how to look for the version here. Googling for it also dint help me. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: I am guessing they have Grails In Action edition 1. That was before Grails v2.x where the database was swapped from HSQL to H2.  See Peter Ledbrooks posting on updating to Grails 2.x here -> http://pledbrook.github.io/grails-howtos/en/upgradeToGrails2.html  @nikhil I realized you want to 'follow' the book but to follow it very closely, you would also probably need to run Grails 1.3.x instead of Grails 2.x.

Comment: Thanks a lot mikemi, will definitely do that. If not I think I ll probably end up having more questions than answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've changed H2 to HSQLDB - you need to add corresponding dependency to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'hsqldb:hsqldb:1.8.0.10'
}
```

Also use the following driver in DataSource.groovy:

```
driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
```

Comment: That's a significant downgrade.